# Mediawiki category infobox parameter

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I am making a `infobox` template for a wiki I am working on. I want to add a publisher parameter to the `infobox` but I want it to also automatically categorize it.

So for example if I put in

```
publisher = Ocean Software
```

it will automatically link to `Category:Ocean Software`. I can see a switch function. But I don't want to have to manually make a list for every publisher, if I can help it, as that would be time consuming.

If this is a question that has been asked before I apologize. But for the life in me I can't think of what it could be called.

Answer (score 3):

To reuse the value set for publisher call it again for the category. In the template add:

```
[[Category:{{{publisher}}}]]
```